C# - Constrain generic type that inherits from a generic class that of any type
Say you have three generic classes: ClassA<T>, ClassB<T> and ClassC<T>. Can you constrain them in the following manner in some way?
public class ClassA<T1> : ClassB<T1> where T1 : ClassC<T2>
{
  // ...
}

And then somehow define T2 to be an arbitrary type?

Only if you declare T2 as a generic type parameter, i.e. ClassA<T1, T2>.

@JonasH This just shifts the problem one layer up in the chain, and I'll still have to define T2 when using ClassA. The point is to have it accept anything that implements ClassC<T2>, regardless of the actual type of T2.

That's not how generic types work in C#, though. ClassC<Type1> and ClassC<Type2> are completely unrelated types. You could get away with using an Interface, maybe.

^^ Like public class ClassA<T1> : ClassB<T1> where T1 : IUsable and public class ClassC<T2> : IUsable. Or a non-generic baseclass might work, too.

=> https://dotnetfiddle.net/mndrRq

@Fildor — IUsable? No, the problem is simpler, nothing has to implement an additional interface. Please see my solution. Also, ClassC<Type1> and ClassC<Type2> are quite related, and nothing prevents introducing desired type constraints.

@JonasH — Why you did not elaborate on your correct comment to post a complete answer? I noticed your comment after I posted my complete answer, but decided to leave it posted, as your comment is not complete and might cause incomplete understanding. Of course, I credited your comment.

@SergeyAKryukov No, it's not that simple. "And then somehow define T2 to be an arbitrary type?" is the deal-breaker here. What you suggest has been explicitly turned down by OP. Also: For the compiler C<T1> and C<T2> are two distinct, unrelated types regardless the relation between T1 and T2. If you think otherwise: citation needed.

^^ "What you suggest has been explicitly turned down by OP" - which is also the reason why @wohlstad deleted his answer (I suppose), which you have probably not enough reps to see. But there was a very similar answer to that.

@Fildor — Arbitrary type? Yes, it is an arbitrary type. Mentally change T2 into some T12 — everything else will be the same. When you instantiate ClassA, you can pick two arbitrary independent types. Relationships between T1 and T2 are totally irrelevant. How T2 is not arbitrary? And I don't see where OP turned it down. It doesn't tell me anything, as I don't see any motivation or comments to my answer. Maybe this person is missing something. Maybe you are missing something, too, because you did not provide any sound argument against my suggestion.

@SergeyAKryukov "This just shifts the problem one layer up in the chain, and I'll still have to define T2 when using ClassA." - dbm. 2nd Comment on the question.

@dbm — “The point is to have it accept anything that implements ClassC, regardless of the actual type of T2”. If you think of it, you will see that this is strictly equivalent to non-generic in place of ClassC. Please see the new section in my answer, Added.

@Fildor — “The point is to have it accept anything that implements ClassC, regardless of the actual type of T2”. Thank you for bringing my attention to this point, I answered the inquirer. If you think of it, you will see that this is strictly equivalent to non-generic in place of ClassC. Please see the new section in my answer, Added.

@JonasH — I also responded to the objection against your first suggestion in your first comment. Please see my updated answer, section Added.

Like this:
class ClassB<T>{ /* ... */ }
class ClassC<T>{ /* ... */ }

class ClassA<T1, T2> : ClassB<T1> where T1 : ClassC<T2> {  /* ... */  }

Also, note that you need compatible accessibility. If you want to make class ClassA public, ClassB and ClassC should also become public.
JonasH provided you with a correct hint, but not a complete answer (please see comments), so I decided to post my complete answer.
Added:
I can see your response in comments:

The point is to have it accept anything that implements ClassC<T2>, regardless of the actual type of T2.

It means that the piece of code in question is inadequate to this situation. It is strictly equivalent to having non-generic ClassC. And this is because only this class depends on T2, that is, T2 is anything. To understand it, we can look at the possible set of different instantiations. The alternative declarations then can be as follows:
class ClassB<T> { /* ... */ }
class ClassC { /* ... */ }

class ClassA<T1> : ClassB<T1> where T1 : ClassC { }

// So far, everything was generic.
// Now let's instantiate,
// that is prepare complete classes from generic ones:

class ClassDerivedC<T> : ClassC { /* ... */ }
class ClassCompleteC : ClassDerivedC<string> { /* ... */ }
class ClassCompleteA : ClassA<ClassCompleteC> { /* ... */ }

// or directly

class Sample {
    internal void Demo() {
        var instance = new ClassA<ClassCompleteC>();
        // ...
    }
}

Let's see what happens here. It is not important that ClassCompleteC is derived from some generic class after its instantiation. This is done only for example because you probably meant to use a generic class like ClassC. But the required flexibility comes from the non-generic ClassC, it may or may not use a generic mechanism, but you make a final choice during instantiation. Also, in this example, ClassA<ClassCompleteC> is ClassB, as defined in the generic class ClassA. Everything works like you asked for.
